# VBA - How to use ShellExecute to force the computer to Sleep (not Hibernate)

Tags: vba, shell, cmd

I'm using ShellExecute on VBA to force the computer to Sleep (not Hibernate), for that to be done I need to disable hibernation. I've entered rundll32.exe but I'm getting an error in the "powercfg.cpl -hibernate off".

I've also tried:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

and

```
powercfg -hibernate off
```

```vb
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                                                                ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                                                ByVal lpszOp As String, _
                                                                ByVal lpszFile As String, _
                                                                ByVal lpszParams As String, _
                                                                ByVal lpszDir As String, _
                                                                ByVal FsShowCmd As Long) As Long
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1

Sub DoSleep()
    ShellExecute 0, "runas", "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe", "powercfg.cpl -h off", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
    ShellExecute 0, "runas", "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe", "powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
    ShellExecute 0, "runas", "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe", "powercfg.cpl -hibernate on", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After  quite a bit of trial and error I found the solution. This will put your computer in sleep mode through VBA:

```vb
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                                                            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                                            ByVal lpszOp As String, _
                                                            ByVal lpszFile As String, _
                                                            ByVal lpszParams As String, _
                                                            ByVal lpszDir As String, _
                                                            ByVal FsShowCmd As Long) As Long
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1

Sub DoSleep()
    ShellExecute 0, "runas", "powercfg.exe", "/hibernate off", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
    Shell "C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0"
    ShellExecute 0, "runas", "powercfg.exe", "/hibernate on", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
End Sub
```